# Disabling SMB Entirely on Non-Domain PCs

Tags: windows, networking, smb, smb2

In an environment with PCs that have no domain connectivity where the only network connectivity is possibly to a networked printer, what are the implications of disabling SMB entirely? Imagine a local library, where there are (5) PCs and a printer on the same subnet. SMB should not be needed and merely presents a security problem. Can it be safely disabled (v1, v2, and v3) without problems?

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer to your "can SMB be disabled without problems" question, you will need to make it less broad, before I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In an environment with PCs that have no domain connectivity where the
>   only network connectivity is possibly to a networked printer, what are
>   the implications of disabling SMB entirely?

Based on the information provided by the article it does not appear that disabling SMB would prevent you from using a network printer.

> Can it be safely disabled (v1, v2, and v3) without problems?

It is far easier to quote what features are deactivated if you disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3.

> In Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, disabling SMBv2 deactivates
>   the following functionality:
>
> - Request compounding - allows for sending multiple SMB 2 requests as a single network request
> - Larger reads and writes - better use of faster networks
> - Caching of folder and file properties - clients keep local copies of folders and files
> - Durable handles - allow for connection to transparently reconnect to the server if there is a temporary disconnection
> - Improved message signing - HMAC SHA-256 replaces MD5 as hashing algorithm
> - Improved scalability for file sharing - number of users, shares, and open files per server greatly increased
> - Support for symbolic links
> - Client oplock leasing model - limits the data transferred between the client and server, improving performance on high-latency networks
>     and increasing SMB server scalability
> - Large MTU support - for full use of 10-gigabye (GB) Ethernet
> - Improved energy efficiency - clients that have open files to a server can sleep

Additionally,

> In Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Windows Server 2012, and
>   Windows Server 2016, disabling SMBv3 deactivates the following
>   functionality (and also the SMBv2 functionality that's described in
>   the previous list):
>
> - Transparent Failover - clients reconnect without interruption to cluster nodes during maintenance or failover
> - Scale Out – concurrent access to shared data on all file cluster nodes
> - Multichannel - aggregation of network bandwidth and fault tolerance if multiple paths are available between client and server
> - SMB Direct – adds RDMA networking support for very high performance, with low latency and low CPU utilization
> - Encryption – Provides end-to-end encryption and protects from eavesdropping on untrustworthy networks
> - Directory Leasing - Improves application response times in branch offices through caching
> - Performance Optimizations - optimizations for small random read/write I/O

[How to enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3 in Windows and Windows Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server)